# Append string using Sed on remote system

Tags: ssh, sed, remote

I'm trying to append PS1 on remote system's `/etc/profile`. Now I have to append this string on more than 70 servers so using `ssh` I will append this PS1 string on all servers. But when I try to send the PS1 it hangs and I have to kill the command

This is the command

```
ssh -v admin@remserv  "sed  '/002/a \ PS1=" \[\e[31m\]\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ \n\n[\u@\h \W]\\$ - \# \[\e[0m\] " /etc/profile' "
```

[image]

What am I missing here ?

## Command edited based on Suggestion

```
> ssh -vt admin@remserv printf "%s\n" "sudo sed -i.bak '/002/a \
> PS1="
> '\[\e[31m\']'\'n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ '\'n'\'n'[\u@\h \W']'\\'$ - '\'# '\[\e[0m\']  " /etc/profile' "
```

Comment: Alternative: instead of the horrible quoting needed to get this sort of thing through `ssh`, you could put your `sed` command in a file, for example `fixprofile`, and use `ssh user@host <fixprofile sed -i.bak -f- /etc/profile`

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh ... "sed  '/002/a \ PS1=" \[\e[31m\]\n--...- \# \[\e[0m\] " /etc/profile' "
              ^             ^                                 ^             ^
```

You have two unquoted double-quotes inside the quoted string, they'll be removed by the shell (on the local side of the ssh connection). Also, the inner single quotes seem to span both the `sed` command and the file name, so after the remote shell handles the quoting, `sed` will get one argument with `/002/a \ ... /etc/profile`. That actually shows on ssh's output in your image.

<sub>(Well, at least that's what comes to mind, double-quoting issues don't work well with my brain, at least without enough coffee.)</sub>

You should be able to debug that by running something like

```
ssh somewhere printf '"%s\n"'  "sed '/002/... /etc/profile' "
```

The `printf` will print the arguments it gets, one per line, so it's easier to see where the string is actually split (echo would join with spaces, so `foo`, `bar`, would look the same as `foo bar`). Double-quotes on the format string to keep the backslash intact to the remote.

Comment: Ok i made change in command which i added in question section but this time it slapped me with "sed: no input files" error

Comment: @OmiPenguin, the new command you posted runs `printf`, I don't see how you can get an error from `sed` with that. Also, I can't tell if the `>` signs are part of the prompt, or part of the input. Can you post the whole command and the exact output? Also, what shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solve this by using '\' characters

Correct Command

```
for i in `cat serverslist`; do  ssh -t admin@$i  "sudo sed -i.bak '/002/a \ PS1="\" '\\'['\\'e[31m'\\']'\\n'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  '\\'n'\\'n['\\'u@'\\'h '\(''\\'W'\)']'\\''\\'$ - '\\'# '\\'['\\'e[0m'\\']   \"" ' /etc/profile " ;done ;
```